# BIRT: How to include NULL values in crosstab average function

Tags: birt, crosstab

When creating aggregations on crosstabs, BIRT ignores NULL values. It leads to incorrect values for AVERAGE. How can I replace NULL with zero. My data is from a stored procedure query.  Thank you !

Leo

Answer (score 0):

So you want the average of [4,null,null,null] to be 1? I think BIRT's calculation 4 is correct instead of this.

But anyway, you could a computed output column XXX_nvl0 to your dataset which is computed as

```
( row["XXX"] == null? 0.0 : row["XXX"] )
```

Then compute the average of XXX_nvl0 instead of XXX.

Comment: Thanks hvb for your reply. Right, I want  [4,null,null,null] to be 1. I think your answer is what I want. but as I mentioned before, my data is from a stored procedure query. There is not null data before group. For example, data group by month, Jan may be null.  How can I set computed output column in this case? Thank you